# How to use WMS in R?

Tags: r, wms

I like to implement a special WMS-layer with `leaflet()` in `R`. But I have no success with the WMS-layer I like to use.

```
library("leaflet")
library("sp")

# this example from the tutorial works
leaflet() %>% addTiles() %>% setView(-93.65, 42.028, zoom = 4) %>%
  addWMSTiles(
    "http://mesonet.agron.iastate.edu/cgi-bin/wms/nexrad/n0r.cgi",
    layers = "nexrad-n0r",
    options = WMSTileOptions(format = "image/png", transparent = TRUE) 
)

# but for my implementation it don't work
leaflet() %>% addTiles() %>% setView(lat = 53.8, lng = 12.6, zoom = 8) %>% 
  addWMSTiles("http://www.umweltkarten.mv-regierung.de/script/mv_a3_wasserschutz_wms.php?", 
              layers = "t2_bib_p", 
              options = WMSTileOptions(format = "image/png")
)
```

I assume that there is a problem with the Coordinate Refernce System. Because the WMS-layer I like to use, have not a standard CRS. So I try to expermented with this `WMSTileOptions()`:

```
crs=CRS("+init=epsg:5650")
```

The idea is to use WMS-Layers as background images for my vector data. The vector data come mainly from shape-files and GPS-data (text files). The purpose is to create maps which i can use in a report. 
If you know other possibles beside `leaflet` to use WMS in R there are also welcome?

Comment: You won't be able to request any layer from the http://mesonet.agron.iastate.edu/cgi-bin/wms/nexrad/n0r.cgi?service=WMS&request=GetCapabilities& WMS service using EPSG:5650, because the service does not support that projection.  So if you need that projection you will need to reproject the image you receive in your client.

Comment: @nmotoken: How is the link you provide related to my question or is it a random example.

Comment: @and that is the same WMS you are talking to in your question code!

Comment: It is the GetCapabilities response to the WMS you reference in line 7 of your code above.  The layer  `<Name>nexrad-n0r</Name>` supports `<CRS>EPSG:4326</CRS> and <CRS>EPSG:26915</CRS>`  Also note the layer is not available at all scales `<MaxScaleDenominator>4.65e+08</MaxScaleDenominator>`

Comment: okay i understand...but how i can go on? can you give me some more discriptions what you mean or some reference where I can look to understand. thx.

Comment: A good place to start would be the [Leaflet documentation](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#icrs) and the [Proj4Leaflet plugin](http://kartena.github.io/Proj4Leaflet/) pages; also take a look at: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/116056/problem-showing-wms-with-epsg3301-projection-using-leaflet